# I wrote a code for linear search in python(recursive). Can somebody tell me why it isn't working? ERROR- maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, jupyter-notebook

```
lister=[4,5,1,2,3,6]

i=0
def Search(arr):
    if arr[i]==3:
        return i
    else:
        if i>=0 and i<=(len(arr)-2):          
            i+1
            return Search(arr)
        else:
            return -1

print(Search(lister))
```

Linear Search using recursion in python.

I don't know why its not working.

Comment: `i+1` does nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: This may be interesting from a purely academic perspective but is not a good technique for performing a linear search. The maximum recursion depth in Python is ~1000. Therefore if your list is longer than the recursion maxima **and** the item is not found before that limit is reached then it will always fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main issues.
The first is that you're not incrementing `i` anywhere. `i+1` doesn't modify `i`, just returns the value of `i+1` which you're not placing anywhere. To increment `i` you should use `i += 1`.
The second is you're not using the externally defined `i` variable in your Search function.

To fix this you could either declare it as global in the start of your method, or pass it as a parameter to your function.

Global method ([less preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20global%20variables%20are,potentially%20leading%20to%20Spaghetti%20code.)):

```py
lister=[4,5,1,2,3,6]

i=0
def Search(arr):
    global i
    if arr[i]==3:
        return i
    else:
        if i>=0 and i<=(len(arr)-2):          
            i+=1
            return Search(arr)
        else:
            return -1

print(Search(lister))
```

And the parameter method (which would be preferable):

```py
lister=[4,5,1,2,3,6]

def Search(arr, i=0):
    if arr[i]==3:
        return i
    else:
        if i>=0 and i<=(len(arr)-2):          
            i+=1
            return Search(arr, i)
        else:
            return -1

print(Search(lister))
```

Comment: Now this is the complete answer imho +1. Global is a bad idea (it will work, but strongly discouraged), the 2nd solution is the one to go with. To the OP you could read about `assignment` and scopes `LEGB` in python (if you still had doubts and wanted to find out in depth why your solution didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `i` variable. You have `i+1` but you don't assign it to `i`. You should have `i=i+1` or `i+=1` for short. This recursive call function is looping infinitely, since `i` doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than explicitly testing that the index is in range, why not use exception handling? You can also manage the any potential recursion "overflow" in this manner. For example:

```
def rfind(_list, val, idx=0):
    try:
        if _list[idx] == val:
            return idx
        return rfind(_list, val, idx+1)
    except (IndexError, RecursionError):
        return -1


print(rfind([1, 2, 3], 2))
print(rfind([1, 2, 3], 4)) # will return None due to IndexError
print(rfind([], 4)) # will return None due to IndexError
print(rfind([0]*2000, 1)) # will return None due to RecursionError
```

**Output:**

```
1
-1
-1
-1
```